# Logistic equation involving population

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$N(t)$ = the number of people in a community exposed to a particular ad.

$N(0) = 500$

$N(1) = 1000$

Find $N(t)$ if it is predicted that the limiting number of people in the community who will see the ad is $50000$.

I'm using the model $dP/dt = k(P) P$, $k(P) = a - bP$.

Here's what I did so far:

$a = 500$, $b = 1000$

$$\frac{dN}{dt} = (500 - 1000N)N$$

$$\frac{dN}{(500 - 1000N)N} = dt$$

$$\frac{2}{500-1000N} + \frac{\frac{1}{500}}{N} = dt$$

$$\frac{1}{250-500N} + \frac{\frac{1}{500}}{N} = dt$$

$$-\ln|250-500N| + \frac{1}{500} \ln|N| = t + C$$

I got stuck here. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differential equation should have shape 
$$\frac{dN}{dt}=kN(50000-N).$$
Solve, using $N(0)$ as your initial condition. Then use $N(1)$ to find $k$.